# How do I write to a file in php?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, createfile

I am getting the source of a page as follows:

```
<? $txt = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/file');
echo $txt; ?>
```

and printing it on the screen but to be honest I actually want to replace an existing html file with it every 1 min. (I will be opening the file every 1 min.)

How could I do this?

Comment: Why do you even need a PHP script to do this?  Have you tried using  `wget http://stats.pingdom.com/file -o /path/to/the/file/locally` and add it to your crontab `*/1 * * * *` to run every minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've learned to use file_get_contents() then consider his sister function [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$txt = file_get_contents('http://stats.pingdom.com/file'); 
file_put_contents('/path/to/my/file.html',$txt);
```

To run it every minute, look at something like cron (or its equivalent on your operating platform of choice)

Comment: because I am getting this: Warning: file_put_contents(/home/xyz/public_html/stats/stats.html) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/xyz/public_html/index.php on line 3

Comment: It needs to be a filesystem path, from the filesystem root; not a path from the web root