# Create a php file

Tags: php

Is there any script that can make a file in a directory specified?
like

`<?php`

`createfile("hi.txt","/home/public_html/files");`

`?>`

Comment: [`file_put_contents("/path/filename.txt", "write this stuff to file...");`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create file on server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133999/how-do-i-create-file-on-server)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752904/write-to-create-file-in-php

Comment: [Use fopen() and fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
Shortform - file_put_contents()

Comment: @redskins80 dont forget `fclose()`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
<?php

file_put_contents("/home/public_html/files/hi.txt", "content");

?>
```

Or [touch](http://php.net/touch) if you don't need the content and just want to be sure the file is created:

```
<?php

touch("/home/public_html/files/hi.txt");

?>
```

Comment: @MatthewJones go to the links. The manual has a lot of examples and better description of each function.

Comment: @MatthewJones - I agree with meze, the links are more than enough to get you started. If you are beginning in PHP, I'd recommend some tutorials/books together with some solid study - it's the best way to get past the beginner phase `:)`

Comment: Thanks! Neat solution

Answer (score 1):

Also try `fopen("/path/to/file", 'w')`

"w" will according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) "If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. "

Answer (score 0):

yes [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

`file_put_contents("/home/public_html/files/hi.txt",$data);`

Answer (score 0):

You can/should use native PHP function:

```
file_put_contents('/home/public_html/files/hi.txt', 'lorem ipsum')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://php.net/touch#100337) is for some people asking whether to use `file_put_contents()` or `touch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
fwrite($file = fopen($filename, "w"), "New content");
fclose($file);
```

If file doesn't contain any contents:

```
fclose($file = fopen($filename, "w"));
```

Also, check if file exists with [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to prevent clearing contents of an existing file:

```
if (!file_exists($filename))
    fclose($file = fopen($filename, "w"));
```